# Program uploading image in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to make an "upload" button using php and html and save the image inside the mysql database. Using mysqli , I realised that my database connection is correct , but however , i still get the same error that "Problem uploading image." . Can anyone explain to me what I did wrong?

member.php

```
<form action="member.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    File:
    <input type="file" name="image" /><input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
<?php
$mysqli=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root','users') or die("Database Error");

 $file = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
 if (!isset($file))
    echo "Please select an image.";
 else
 {
    $image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
    $image_name = addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
    $image_size = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

    if($image_size==FALSE)
        echo "That's not an image file.";
    else {
        if (!$insert = mysqli_query("INSERT INTO store VALUES ('','$image_name','$image')"))
         echo "Problem uploading image.";
        else {
            echo "Image uploaded.";
        }
    }

 }

?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Steve

Comment: Change this: `if (!$insert = mysqli_query("INSERT INTO store VALUES ('','$image_name','$image')"))` to this: `if (!mysqli_query("INSERT INTO store VALUES ('','$image_name','$image')"))`

Comment: Right now, there's insufficient information to see what the problem is, obviously mysqli_query fails, but we don't really know why. you can use the method mysqli_error to fetch the errors, and edit your post accordingly.

Comment: @Jonathon it still says problem uploading image mate.

Comment: @Arend any idea how I might insert it inside my code ?

Comment: Before you have  `echo "Problem uploading image.";` put echo `echo mysqli_error();`. Make sure to put curly braces around the IF though.

Comment: @Jonathon mate , it doesn't show any error mate.

Comment: just see the column datatype in your database for image it should be blob.

Comment: @suchit i put it as longblob.

Comment: And what is your table design like? (I'm suspecting column count doesn't match)

Comment: my table design is : 

id    int(11) nn auto_increment
name varchar(1000) 
image longblob

Comment: @NyanLinStev: http://pastebin.com/CpQJ9SwM this might work.

Comment: On an unreleated note: your code is suspectable to SQL injection this way. It is highly recommended to use prepared statements to secure your site. What if I were to upload a malicious file with the contents: '; delete from store; ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you must first upload file !

Try this code:

```
<?php
$mysqli=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root','users') or die("Database Error");

 $file = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
 if (!isset($file))
    echo "Please select an image.";
 else
 {
    $uploaddir = '/var/www/uploads/';
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
          echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";

          $image = file_get_contents($uploadfile);
          $image_name = $_FILES['image']['name']);

          if (!$insert = mysqli_query("INSERT INTO store VALUES ('','$image_name','$image')"))
             echo "Problem uploading image.";
          else {
            echo "Image uploaded.";
           }



    } else {
         echo "Possible file upload attack!\n";
    }


 }

?>
```

Comment: If You saving content of file to database, remember to delete file from  $uploaddir = '/var/www/uploads/';

Answer (score 1):

use  `mysqli_error();` to get the exact error. It will produce you the which error is present in insert into database.

```
<?php
$mysqli=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root','users') or die("Database Error");

 $file = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
 if (!isset($file))
    echo "Please select an image.";
 else
 {
    $uploaddir = '/var/www/uploads/';
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
          echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";

          $image = file_get_contents($uploadfile);
          $image_name = $_FILES['image']['name']);
          $insert = mysqli_query("INSERT INTO store VALUES ('','$image_name','$image')") or die(mysqli_error());
          if (!$insert)
             echo "Problem uploading image.";
          else {
            echo "Image uploaded.";
           }

 } else {
         echo "Possible file upload attack!\n";
    }


 }

?>
```

if there is any error in your query then it will show. Now easily you can remove error and image will be upload.

Answer (score 0):

Try below syntax for mysqli_query:

```
$con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root','users');
mysqli_query ( $con, "INSERT INTO store VALUES ('','$image_name','$image')" );
```

Pass connection object as a first parameter in your code.